# Karate - substring - lastindexof trim/ strip/ slice help needed

Tags: karate

I have a tricky authentication issue which requires multiple calls to ultimately obtain an access-token.

I am currently stumbling on the conversion of a returned correlation-id to a correct format.

The correlationID from a post response is returned as: Id-c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 0; Id-c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 2
I need to convert to c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db

I have tried with * def serviceId1 = correlationID.substring(correlationID.lastIndexOf('-')+ 1).trim()

which is resulting in c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 2

I need to strip the " 2" value from the backend of the id to make it
from: 'c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 2'
to: 'c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db'

I have tried many ways but cant refine to get working - ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED

The code below:
Scenario: Obtaining access_token

```
* def correlationID = 'Id-c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 0; Id-c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 2'
* def serviceId1 = correlationID.substring(correlationID.lastIndexOf('-')+ 1).trim()
* print 'correlationID ' + correlationID
* print 'serviceID ' + serviceId1
```

is resulting in c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 2 ( I want to strip the trailing " 2" - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def temp = 'c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db 2'
* def pos = temp.lastIndexOf(' ')
* def fixed = temp.substring(0, pos)
* match fixed == 'c5ea93607b0682a76040b5db'
```

Comment: Thanks @peterthomas you are a legend, that did the trick. Also thanks for great documentation. I also needed to convert string to json and the doco/example made it easy. This is complete and can be closed.